# A problem involving complex numbers and polynomials to prove that $f(z) + f(−z) = 0$ for all $z ∈ C$.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, complex-numbers

Let $f : C → C$ be a function such that $f(z)f(iz) = z^2$ for all $z ∈ C$. Prove that $f(z) + f(−z) = 0$ for all $z ∈ C$. Also, find such a function.

What I did was take a $f(x)$ of the form or as a polynomial as $a_n x^n +  a_{n-1} x^{n-1} +\ldots+a_0$ and substituted $z$ and $iz$ and then some manipulations to do... But failed. I need help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substituting $iz$ for $z$,
$$f(iz)f(-z)=(iz)^2=-z^2$$
Thus
$$f(iz)(f(z)+f(-z))=0$$
Either $f(iz)=0$ for all $z\in\mathbb C$, implying $f(z)=0$ and $f(z)+f(-z)=0$ over the same domain, or $f(z)+f(-z)=0$ outright.

An example $f$ is $f(z)=ze^{-i\pi/4}$.

Answer (score 3):

Substituting $iz$ instead of $z$ in the functional equation

$$f(iz)f(-z) = -z^2$$

Adding the two, we get

$$f(iz)(f(z) + f(-z)) = 0$$

Comment: Got it... .... And can you guess Such a function which satisfies that